# Serialize an object using DataContractJsonSerializer as a json array

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a class which contains a list of items. 
I want to serialize an instance of this class to json using the DataContractJsonSerializer as a json array. eg.

```
class MyClass 
{
    List<MyItem> _items;
}

class MyItem
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

When serialized to json it should be like this :

`[{"Name":"one","Description":"desc1"},{"Name":"two","Description":"desc2"}]`

Comment: And what is the problem you have? Do you have a question about this?

Comment: Also FWIW you should check out the Json.NET serializer as it is far more performant than the WCF Json serializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
public class MyItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var graph = new List<MyItem>
        {
            new MyItem { Name = "one", Description = "desc1" },
            new MyItem { Name = "two", Description = "desc2" }
        };
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(graph.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), graph);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, List<MyItem> HAS to be member of MyClass, and MyClass should be serialized as array... so graph would be instance if MyClass and the items will be added to this instance